# UICollectionView stuck in infinite loop in iOS 7 since I started to use the iOS 8 SDK

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

So I've been updating an app I'm maintaining for iOS 8 but I'm experiencing problems in iOS 7 that I did not have when I was using the iOS 7 SDK.

If I don't touch the code at all it ends op in a loop (90% CPU without stopping) when the code calls into `layoutSubviews`. It changes a bit when I play and pause but `validateLayoutInRect:` always seems to be there.

[image]

When I change `layoutSubviews` in `layoutIfNeeded` it passes but gets stuck in a very similar way after calling the following line:

```
[collectionView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

[image]

*update: enabling and setting auto layouts on the parent view makes it pass `layoutSubviews` as well, that part of the problem might have to do with auto layouts in the xibs but not on the hosting view controller*

To me it seems that it gets stuck calculating the size, changing something that triggers a recalculation and so on. It's weird that it doesn't happen with iOS 7 SDK -> iOS 7 phone and iOS 8 SDK -> iOS 8 phone nor iOS 7 SDK -> iOS 8 phone.

I tried to put NSLog messages at various points where it could surface in my code again but nothing is getting called in a loop. The Collection View is filled by reusing .xib files. I would like to rebuild it to use just storyboards but it's a very complex screen and at this point I am actually not sure if this really is my bug or a bug in the SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I compiled with the iOS 8.1 SDK in Xcode 6.1 things already got a lot better. But there was still one screen crashing. Eventually I figured out some cells ended up being MAXFLOAT high and I needed to add a sanity check before applying that height:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Class class = [[self dataSource] cellClassForIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *classString = NSStringFromClass(class);
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self sizingCells][classString];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [class loadInstanceFromNib];
        [self sizingCells][classString] = cell;
    }

    [[self dataSource] configureCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath excludeKeys:@[@"imageURL", @"image"]];

    CGSize fittingSize = CGSizeMake([collectionView frameSizeWidth], MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize size = [cell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:fittingSize];

    if (size.height > 10000) { // Needed for iOS 8 SDK on iOS 7 device bug AMA-827
        size.height = cell.frame.size.height; // Ridiculous size detected, whipping
    }

    return CGSizeMake([collectionView frameSizeWidth], size.height);
}
```

I arbitrarily decided that anything above 10000 probably wasn't what I intended and put in the cell frame height instead. Works in this case everywhere I need it!

Most of it isn't my code, don't slap me for the old fashioned style of CGRects everywhere ;)

---

I noticed it got downvoted twice. Please tell me what is wrong with this *working* answer.